# Is there a way to filter token contracts based on whether they contain certain code?

Tags: solidity, security, web3.py, filters, vulnerability

Basically if I had a list of 500 token contracts instead of manually going and reading through each token contract, is there a quick and easy function (such as an RPC call method) that checks if the token contract contains a specified text?

Not that this is any interesting function, but let's say I wanted to search for this function:

```
function setBlacklists(address _bots) external onlyOwner {
    require(!bots[_bots]);
    bots[_bots] = true;
}
```

It would be great if the solution could also incorporate regex, for example in the above function the name "setBlacklists" or variable "bots" may be renamed, but the overarching structure will likely be similar.

This would be great for detecting vulnerabilities en-masse.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is something called function selectors. From solidity docs:

> The first four bytes of the call data for a function call specifies the function to be called. It is the first (left, high-order in big-endian) four bytes of the Keccak-256 (SHA-3) hash of the signature of the function. The signature is defined as the canonical expression of the basic prototype without data location specifier, i.e. the function name with the parenthesised list of parameter types. Parameter types are split by a single comma - no spaces are used.

So you can calculate the function selector by manually and you will have 4 bytes identifier. And maybe you can ask other functions to do they have this function?

This is how EVM doing for us. If the contract doesn't have that function selector, run the fallback function.